# How post a large blob to server using XMLHttpRequest and asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, getusermedia

I am using your RecordRTC in mvc to record and post large size video. 
It works fine when I have 2-3 min recording but fails to post when I have around
8-10 min recording.I can see 404 controller action in this case.

```
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName); 
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob); 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open('POST', '/Admin/Videos/PostRecordedAudioVideo'); 
request.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `webconfig` file add the below line into the `<system.web>` tag

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="6000000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

It will allow to upload large file size at the server. It just extend the limit `4MB` to `2GB` and it also extends the execution timeout. So if your file is large than it takes time to upload.

You does not posted the code so, I assume that you can not added the above line of code into your `webconfig`.

Comment: Thanks, Let me test this.

Comment: If it solve your problem, feel free to mark as an answer.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, can you pls tell me how to post this data to server in asp.net webform?